# UDP image livestream from Android device to C# desktop application

Tags: c#, android, kotlin, udp

After searching a lot, on how to do it and not finding any good solutions, I implemented my own UDP livestream from an Android device to a C#/WPF desktop application. It works, however, since I get complete JPEG images from the camera2 API each frame in android, I need to wait until I have data for the complete image before I can display it (instead of updating image areas). All in all, slicing up the images and putting them together on the other end is a pain. I ended up buffering up to 4 images, always discarding the oldest one as new ones come along. I still have to implement connection losses and so on...

Anyway, here is the Android side (kotlin):

```
// gets called as soon as a new image is available
//livestreamSocket is a DatagramSocket, connection is basically set up at this point.
fun sendLivestreamImage(img: Image) { 
    if(livestreamSocket.isClosed) return

    /** Protocol: [8bytes timestamp][4byte imagesize][4bytes startindex][4bytes payloadlength][x bytes payload] */

    var buffer = img.planes[0].buffer
    var imgSize = buffer.remaining()

    var payloadSize = liveStreamPacketSize - livestreamHeaderSize

    var numbPackets = (imgSize / payloadSize) + 1

    //Log.d(TAG, "size: ${imgSize}, numbPackets: ${numbPackets}")

    for(i in 1..numbPackets){

        if(i < numbPackets){
            var bytes = ByteArray(liveStreamPacketSize)
            var startIndex = buffer.position()
            var headbuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(livestreamHeaderSize).putLong(img.timestamp).putInt(8, imgSize).putInt(12, startIndex).putInt(16, payloadSize)
            headbuffer.rewind()
            headbuffer.get(bytes, 0, livestreamHeaderSize)
            buffer.get(bytes, livestreamHeaderSize, payloadSize)
            var packet = DatagramPacket(bytes, bytes.size, udpLivestreamAddress, udpLivestreamPort)
            livestreamSocket.send(packet)
        }
        else {
            payloadSize = buffer.remaining()
            var startIndex = buffer.position()
            var bytes = ByteArray(payloadSize + livestreamHeaderSize)
            var headbuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(livestreamHeaderSize).putLong(img.timestamp).putInt(8, imgSize).putInt(12, startIndex).putInt(16, payloadSize)
            headbuffer.rewind()
            headbuffer.get(bytes, 0, livestreamHeaderSize)
            buffer.get(bytes, livestreamHeaderSize, payloadSize)
            var packet = DatagramPacket(bytes, bytes.size, udpLivestreamAddress, udpLivestreamPort)
            livestreamSocket.send(packet)
        }
    }
}
```

On the C# side I have the following function listening to the UDP connection:

```
/// <summary>
/// waits and receives livestream images
/// </summary>
public async Task ReceiveLivestream(IProgress<BitmapImage> imageReceivedProgress)
{

    var udpEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, GenDefInt.UdpLiveStreamPort);
    liveStreamReceiver = new UdpClient(udpEndpoint);
    var imgBuilder = new LivestreamImageBuilder();

    while (true)
    {
        var recv = await liveStreamReceiver.ReceiveAsync();

        long timestamp = IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(BitConverter.ToInt64(recv.Buffer, 0));
        int imageSize = IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(BitConverter.ToInt32(recv.Buffer, 8));
        int startIndex = IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(BitConverter.ToInt32(recv.Buffer, 12));
        int payloadLength = IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(BitConverter.ToInt32(recv.Buffer, 16));

            var img = imgBuilder.CreateImageFromUdpPackets(timestamp, imageSize, startIndex, payloadLength, recv.Buffer);
            if (img == null) continue;
            else imageReceivedProgress.Report(img); //reports the updated image back to the viewmodel of the application, where it will update the GUI
    }
}
```

The important parts are happening in the `LivestreamImageBuilder` class:

```
public class LivestreamImageBuilder
{
    #region Private Fields
    private byte[][] imageBuffers = new byte[4][];
    private int[] copiedBytes = new int[4];
    private long[] timeStamps = new long[4];
    #endregion

    #region Public Properties
    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    #endregion

    #region Private Methods
    /// <summary>
    /// returns a BitmapImage from a full imagebuffer bytearray
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="imgBuffer"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private BitmapImage GetImageFromBuffer(byte[] imgBuffer)
    {

        var img = new BitmapImage();
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imgBuffer))
        {
            img.BeginInit();
            img.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            img.StreamSource = ms;
            img.EndInit();
        }
        return img;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Public Methods
    /// <summary>
    /// Manages and fills up to four image buffers with data from the latest udp packet
    /// if the respective image buffer is full, returns a BitmapImage, else returns null
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="timeStamp"></param>
    /// <param name="imageSize"></param>
    /// <param name="startIndex"></param>
    /// <param name="payloadLength"></param>
    /// <param name="buffer"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public BitmapImage CreateImageFromUdpPackets(long timeStamp, int imageSize, int startIndex, int payloadLength, byte[] buffer)
    {
        for (uint i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            if (timeStamp == timeStamps[i])
            {
                Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 20, imageBuffers[i], startIndex, payloadLength);
                copiedBytes[i] += payloadLength;
                if (copiedBytes[i] >= imageSize)
                {
                    return GetImageFromBuffer(imageBuffers[i]);
                }
                else return null;
            }
        }

        //find oldest buffer
        int oldest = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < timeStamps.Length; i++)
        {
            if (timeStamps[i] < timeStamps[oldest])
            {
                oldest = i;
            }
        }

        timeStamps[oldest] = timeStamp;
        imageBuffers[oldest] = new byte[imageSize];
        copiedBytes[oldest] = 0;
        Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 20, imageBuffers[oldest], startIndex, payloadLength);
        copiedBytes[oldest] += payloadLength;
        if (copiedBytes[oldest] >= imageSize)
        {
            return GetImageFromBuffer(imageBuffers[oldest]);
       }
        else return null;

    }
    #endregion
}
```

Again, it works. I just found it weird that I couldn't find solutions to this (I'm sure, somebody has already solved this in a better, more efficient way), so I would appreciate all kinds of suggestions for improvements, errors I overlooked or any other kind of input :)

Obviously, If there are questions concerning the code, please just ask away -> I'm a bit lazy with comments^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no experience with Kotlin, so I'll purely be focusing on the C# part

---

**Empty `#region`s**:
Delete them, they just take up unnecessary space. In the same vein, I personally add an empty line after the `#region` and just before `endregion`, makes it more readable (IMO).

**Naming**:
[Microsoft's own naming conventions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions) aren't complete, so I follow what everyone else, and even [Microsoft themselves](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/1870441efdc00a6c253c2a5c54c20a313fb56ee2/src/HttpClientFactory/Polly/src/PolicyHttpMessageHandler.cs#L77) does. Namely: Prefix private members in a class with an underscore. This turns your `LivestreamImageBuilder` member declarations into this:

```csharp
private byte[][] _imageBuffers = new byte[4][];
private int[] _copiedBytes = new int[4];
private long[] _timeStamps = new long[4];
```

This then allows you to use the proper name as the parameter in `GetImageFromBuffer`, i.e

```csharp
private BitmapImage GetImageFromBuffer(byte[] imageBuffer)
```

Even though MS's naming conventions are sparce, they tell us:

> DO NOT use abbreviations or contractions as part of identifier names.

So it depends on how pedantic you want to be. Is `img` an abbreviation? Yes, does basically everyone understand that it means `image`? Also yes, but you should still *technically* not call it `img`.

**Documentation**:
You are using XMLDocs, but their not quite complete. For example, you have zero documentation concerning parameters which I think is quite important. Especially when they could be confusing, like `long timeStamp`. Why is it a `long` and not a `DateTime`? What are acceptable values? or is anything not acceptable? Also there is no documentation for what a method can return. In your `CreateImageFromUdpPackets` method I think it's especially important, because it can return `null`, a simple

> Returns the newest Image received, if none are completely received returns null

would suffice.

**Comments:**
I know, I know, they're a PITA, but important. Some code blocks are quite difficult to understand, for example:

```csharp
Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 20, imageBuffers[i], startIndex, payloadLength);
copiedBytes[i] += payloadLength;
if (copiedBytes[i] >= imageSize)
{
    return GetImageFromBuffer(imageBuffers[i]);
}
// ...
```

Could use a comment, something like

> Copies newly received image into the local buffer, and returns the image if it's complete

**For loop**:
Currently you're iterating through your `timeStamps` in a for loop with a fixed max, this should be replaced by this:

```csharp
for (int i = 0; i < timeStamps.Length; i++)
{
    if (timeStamp == timeStamps[i])
   // ...
}
```

Because what if you decide you want to keep 5 images around? Or 3? Or however many.

**If else statements**:
You have multiple unnecessary `else` statements, they should be removed. So turn

```csharp
if (copiedBytes[i] >= imageSize)
{
    return GetImageFromBuffer(imageBuffers[i]);
}
else return null;
```

Into

```csharp
if (copiedBytes[i] >= imageSize)
    return GetImageFromBuffer(imageBuffers[i]) // The curly braces can optionally be left out

return null;
```

**Custom network data class**:
Why not use a custom network data class instead of passing 5 parameters to your `CreateImageFromUdpPackets`? You could even implement methods on it construct it directly from a byte array. Like so:

```csharp
public class LivestreamImagePacket
{
    public long Timestamp {get; set;}

    public int ImageSize {get; set;}

    public int StartIndex {get; set;}

    public int PayloadLength {get; set;}

    public LiveStreamImagePacket(long timestamp, int imageSize, int startIndex, int payloadLength)
    {
        Timestamp = timestamp;
        ImageSize = imageSize;
        StartIndex = startIndex;
        PayloadLength = payloadLength;
    }

    public static LivestreamImagePacket FromBytes(byte[] bytes)
    {
        long timestamp = IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(BitConverter.ToInt64(recv.Buffer, 0));
        int imageSize = IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(BitConverter.ToInt32(recv.Buffer, 8));
        int startIndex = IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(BitConverter.ToInt32(recv.Buffer, 12));
        int payloadLength = IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(BitConverter.ToInt32(recv.Buffer, 16));

        return new LivestreamImagePacket(timestamp, imageSize, startIndex, payloadLength);
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```csharp
while (true)
{
    var recv = await liveStreamReceiver.ReceiveAsync();
    var packet = LivestreamImagePacket.FromBytes(recv.Buffer);
    var img = imgBuilder.CreateImageFromUdpPackets(packet, recv.Buffer);
}
```

Of course you'd need to change the `CreateImageFromUdpPackets` signature to this `CreateImageFromUdpPackets(LivestreamImagePacket packet, byte[] buffer)` and replace the usages of `timestamp` with `packet.Timestamp`

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'll make a few adjustments :)